# I am trying to create udp socket and send a string through it. but it gives 10038 error at sendto()

Tags: c++, windows, sockets

I am new to socket programming. I have written a basic function which create a UDP socket and send an array through it. My function create a socket and return 0 in decriptor and when I use sendto() it gives 10038 error.

Here is my code:

```
int ret, a=0;
WSADATA wsa;

if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
{
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if (m_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
   m_socket = (AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM,0);
}

SOCKADDR_IN addr;
char buf[256];
addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
addr.sin_port=htons(1234);
addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

strcpy(buf,"Hallo world!");
if (m_socket != INVALID_SOCKET)
{
 ret=sendto(m_socket,buf,strlen(buf),0,(SOCKADDR*)&addr,sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN));

 if(ret==SOCKET_ERROR)
 {
  printf("Fehler: sendto, fehler code: %d\n",WSAGetLastError());
  a=WSAGetLastError();
  ret=-1;
 }
 CloseSocket();
 WSACleanup();
 m_socket = INVALID_SOCKET;
}
```

Comment: Error code means "Socket operation on nonsocket.". Link to docu: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#WSAENOTSOCK

Comment: I seem to miss the socket call to initialize `m_socket`.

Comment: You omitted the actual call to socket: `m_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM,0);`. The given syntax compiles because ()'s in C/C++ can enclose a list of expressions that are evaluated, and the whole expression has the value of the last entry, i.e. (m_socket = (AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0) simply assigns 0 to m_socket.

Comment: i initialized the m_socket in constructor as m_socket=INVALID_SOCKET

Comment: Also - if you open winsock.h you can see all the error code names which should provide better clues to what is going on. The macro adds 10000 so just search for `38` to find your error.

Comment: @ChrisBecke you are right. i missed socket in socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM,0). Thanks. How can I accept your answere as i am new to this

Comment: Did you at any stage consider looking up what Winsock error 10038 means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has:

```
m_socket = (AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM,0);
```

for initializing `m_socket`. This will assign `0` to `m_socket` not allocate a socket from the OS. Thus you get this non-socket error.

You might use:

```
m_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM,0);
```

to cover up the typo.

Comment: C would have been better off without the comma operator.

Comment: Yep. I forget socket in it. I was trying since yesterday and was wondering why this simple program does not work.

Comment: @I004 sometimes, the error is so obvious that you just cannot see it, no matter how hard you look:)

Comment: can I write client and server program in the same project

Comment: @I004: this is a new question, probably you should ask with the appropriate context information!. But basically, what prevents you from doing so? There might be reasons, however, for using separate projects  depending on your build environment or IDE.

Comment: I have written server and client in separate projects in one solution and run it one after another. when it comes at the line where recvfrom() function there is black window pop up and then do nothing.

Comment: @I004: surely not related with project structure. Plaese, ask this with a new question shwoing the relevant code, the sequence of operation, what you expoect and what you observe, and anything you already know whats happening or not happening with the shown case.

Comment: yep some one downvoted my question and now i cannot ask question quickly. i have to wait. socket programming is not the main task of my thesis. it is used only for testing one condition and it taking long time as i am not familiar to it.